# Dom and XPath scraping - What wrong here?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I need to scrape a length of text from a webpage from the internet, I am using the dom and xpath to find the data, however I cant seem to select the exact information I need. Here is my code so far, the problem is with the item(0)->nodeValue section - this works for my other scrapes i have for another page, however not this one.

```
$argos_html = file_get_html('http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/9282197/Trail/searchtext%3EIPOD+TOUCH.htm');

$dom_argos= new DOMDocument();
$dom_argos->loadHTML($argos_html);

$xpath_argos = new DOMXpath($dom_argos);

$expr_currys = "/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[5]/ul/li[3]/span";
$nodes_argos = $xpath_argos->query($expr_argos);

$argos_stock_data = $nodes_argos->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Could anyone show me where I am going wrong ? because I always get an error, which relates to the ->item(0)->nodeValue; part, however if I comment that out, theres no error, but theres no data collected at all...

Should it perhaps  be just ->nodeValue;

I understand this may be down to page structures, but I am new to all of this!
Thx

Comment: The error is probably because you have no elements selected: you can't call `nodeValue` when there's no node! You probably have an error in your XPath -- it's horrifically complex, so I'm not surprised.  Look to see if you can find a simpler way of specifying which element you want. Element IDs would be a good place to start.

Comment: If you get an error, tell us what it is. It may mean nothing to you, but it probably means something to someone on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Running your code, I first get :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: expr_argos
Warning: DOMXPath::query() [domxpath.query]: Invalid expression
```

So, first of all, make sure you are using something valid for your XPath query -- for example, you should have this :

```
$nodes_argos = $xpath_argos->query($expr_currys);
```

instead of what you currently have :

```
$nodes_argos = $xpath_argos->query($expr_argos);
```

Then, you get the following error :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

on the following line :

```
$argos_stock_data = $nodes_argos->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Basically, this means you are trying to read a property, `nodeValue`, on something that is not an object : `$nodes_argos->item(0);`

I'm guessing your XPath query is not valid ; so, the call to the `xpath()` method doesn't return anything interesting.

You should check your *(quite a bit too long to be easy to understand)* XPath query, making sure it matches something in your HTML page.

Comment: Cheers for your reply, oh no its me copying and pasting again, thats why currys is in there, it should have all been argos. I have multiple online retailers that I am trying to scrape. Thanks for your explanation, I'm gonna get on and code some more!

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is fine when I use it in Firefox, but it won't work with DOM, which is not surprising. I assume you got your XPath from some sort of browser plugin able to return the path for certain elements. However, you should not trust XPaths returned by browser plugins because browsers will modify the DOM through JavaScript and add implied values where necessary. Use the raw sourcecode instead.

Your XPath evaluates to "Home delivery within 2 days" in Firefox, which is not what I would expect in a variable called "stock_data". But anyway, this should do it:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/9282197/Trail/searchtext%3EIPOD+TOUCH.htm');
libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query(
    '/html/body//div[@id="deliveryInformation"]/ul/li[@class="home"]/span'
);
echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue; // "Home delivery within 2 days"
```

Comment: Your correct, I used a plugin! and also the variables I forgot to change it over to argos, currys is another of the retailers I am trying to get data from. Also I need a method of checking if a product is in stock, so therefore I thought how would a retailer say on thier website if a product was in stock, and check that with an IF statement, so if the final veriable did not contain "home delivery...." then it would return as false/not in stock! I am very new to all this and have taken on a challenging project! anyways much appriecated for your reply, now to code!

Comment: @James please review the answers you have been given so far and either accept the one that solved your problem or update and improve your question to point out why none of these solve your problem, so people have a chance to improve their answers. thanks.