# Can't get picture url by Parsing

Tags: php, html, parsing, xpath

Im building a script that give me an product array by parsing html from a list of websites.

I believe that Im doing everything right.. But for some reason i have alots of difficulty with only one website Makita.ca

So.. Im using DOMXPath for retrieving element. i am providing the RAW html that im getting from makita.ca

What picture i want to get is those on the pictures that are on the left

please also note that the only thing i need is the link of the image and not the actual 
image.

the folowing image page is at http://www.makita.ca/index2.php?event=tool&id=100 [image]

```
    $productArray = array();
    $Dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$Dom -> loadHTML($this->html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($Dom);
    echo $xpath -> query('//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/a/img')->length;
        if($xpath -> query('//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table')->length > 0)
        {
            for($i=0;$i<$xpath->query('//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr')->length;$i++)
            {
                if($xpath->query('//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]/tr/td[1]/table/tr[4]/td/table/tr['.$i.']/td/div/a/img') > 0)
                    $productArray['picture'][] = $xpath -> query('//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]/tr/td[1]/table/tr[4]/td/table/tr['.$i.']/td/div/a/img')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            }
        }
```

Do you see what is my mistake ? since now im really lost.

Edit:

ok for test purposes i am echoing the length of the query() method witch should give me how much element match the query

So I retyped to hole query down so they can't have any non asci character
So i retyped the hole query '//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9gHt.png)/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9gHt.png)/td/div‌​/a/img'
then the result is 0

So i removed the end of the query part by part..

```
//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1]/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr[1]/td/div‌​/a = 0
//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1]/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr[1]/td/div‌​ = 0
//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1]/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr[1]/td = 0
//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1]/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr[1] = 0
//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1]/table//tr[4]/td/table = 0
//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1]/table//tr[4]/td = 0
//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1]/table//tr = 5
```

Wooo  i got some element matching here !
ok let try the last element witch is the one i need 
so since it is zero based then to get the tr number 5 i need to enter as a path this

```
//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1]/table//tr[4]
```

But I still get 0.... So i dont know what to do any more..

Comment: This is an exact duplicate, removing all the `/tbody` steps is all you need to do. Refer to given reference for details.

Comment: @JensErat Hey thanks guys. but i removed the tbody and still i can't get it working. for starting i just edited echo $xpath -> query('//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1]/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr[1]/td/div/a/img')->length; and it echoing 0

Comment: I'm not sure what's messed up, but one of the characters of the last four axis steps is non-ascii and breaks the query. Try `//*[@id="content_other"]/table[2]//tr/td[1]/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr[1]/td/div/a/img` (I retyped those four steps).

Comment: @JensErat I got something very wierd now.. lol very wierd..  let me edit my original post. Take a look

Comment: try with `//a[@rel="thumbnail"]/@href` instead of the direct path and/or check the markup returned in DOM instead of in a browser. The markup in the browser likely contains implied markup as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689011/dom-and-xpath-scraping-what-wrong-here/5689495#5689495

Comment: XPath is 1-based. The XPath expression I posted works for me. Did you try copy&past'ing it? The expressions you posted are broken for me again. @Gordon: I tried the expression with BaseX (not evaluating any JS, ...) and it works fine (after `/tbody` axis steps are removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//div[@class='product_heading']/ancestor-or-self::table[1]//a/img` selects firstly the "Action Shots", then all the images found under this bloc.

This XPath expression will be more reliable than yours, because of the low number of positional expressions which tends to break easily as the markup changes.

`//div[@class='product_heading']/ancestor-or-self::table[1]//a[@rel='thumbnail']/img` would be a stronger security

Comment: Thanks! Your first xpath work. I was so occupied by the xpath not working that I never thought about rewriting it differently...  Thanks Again

Comment: Sorry, a misplaced `@` character in the second xpath